# Embedded Lua in C take input from STDIN

Tags: c, lua, embed

I'm writing a C app that has an embedded lua script in it.  The Lua script takes input from STDIN. So when I'm running the script from the shell it's like thus:

```
lua myscript.lua < datafile*
```

How do I accomplish this from inside the C code?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want `yourprogram < datafile` to work, or do you want to know how to do equivalent of above inside C, without shell?

Comment: A little of both. I probably didn't explain it incredibly well. In the program (which is kind of a wrapper for a parser script in Lua) I'm getting each line from the datafile (or datafiles, potentially this could later be a FIFO named pipe) inside program. I'm wanting after I have each line to send it as stdin to the lua parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `dup2(2)` system call on descriptor `0` (stdin) and on the descriptor returned by `open(2)` on `datafile`:

```
int fd = open("datafile", O_RDONLY);
dup2(fd, 0);
/* reading from stdin now is in fact reading from datafile */
```

Of course, you need some error-checking in a real-world program.

To implement the behaviour of wildcarding, you may want to look at the `readdir(3)` library function.

Comment: How would I pass the STDIN to the lua_State at that point? That's more along the lines of what I can't figure out.

Comment: This code changes the STDIN for your program (the one that Lua's reading from, just like everybody else) to be the file descriptor. There's nothing to pass in.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to just run your script unmodified (i.e. use `io.stdin` etc.)? Unless you're doing something fancy on C side, it should work out of the box.